# How to isolate x in equation with ln(erfc(x))?

Tags: exponential-function, error-function

I was wondering whether it is possible to isolate $x$ in this equation:

$$
f = 1- \exp\left(\frac{xt}{C^2}\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt(xt)}{C}\right)
$$

I have not come further than
$$
\ln(f-1) + \frac{xt}{C^2}=  \ln\left(\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt(xt)}{C}\right)\right)
$$

I have actual measured values for $f$, $C$, and I know the time, $t$. It thus should be possible with one unknown and one equation to solve for $x$.

I'd greatly appreaciate any help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no analytic solution to this. You'll have to resort to a numerical solution. With a bit of work, it may be possible to find asymptotic solutions when $t\to\infty$, say, and if you're in luck, such an asymptotic solution may be helpful in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

An approximate closed-form solution is possible. We set $y=\frac{\sqrt{x t}}{C}$. Then $f=1-\exp(y^{2})\ \mathrm{erfc}(y)$ or in other terms: $f = 1 - \mathrm{erfcx}(y)$. The exponentially-scaled complementary error function $\mathrm{erfcx}$ is available in many computational environments as it is needed to avoid spurious underflow during numerical computations. For example, in Fortran 2008 it is provides as `ERFC_SCALED`.

C. Ren and A. R. MacKenzie, "Closed-form approximations to the error and complementary error functions and their applications in atmospheric science." *Atmospheric Science Letters* **8**: 70–73 (2007) proposes the analytic approximation

$$\mathrm{erfcx}(y) \approx \frac{a}{(a-1)\sqrt{\pi y^{2}} + \sqrt{\pi y^{2} +a^{2}}}$$

where $a$ should be a constant around $3$. The authors suggest $a=2.7889$ for best results, but here it seems best to use $a=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}\pi} \approx 2.8025$ to simplify the resulting formula:

$$\mathrm{erfcx}(y) \approx \frac{\sqrt{10}}{\left(\sqrt{10 \pi}-2\right)\sqrt{y^2} + \sqrt {4y^{2}+10}}$$

Replacing $y$ with $\frac{\sqrt{x t}}{C}$ results in

$$f \approx 1 - \frac{\sqrt{10}}{\left(\sqrt{10 \pi}-2\right)\sqrt{\frac{t x}{C^{2}}} + \sqrt {\frac{4 t x}{C^{2}}+10}}$$

Wolfram Alpha can solve this for $x$, providing an exact closed-form [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+for+x%3A+f+%3D+1+-+sqrt%2810%29%2F%28%28sqrt%2810+%CF%80%29+-+2%29+sqrt%28%28t+x%29%2Fc%5E2%29+%2B+sqrt%28%284+t+x%29%2Fc%5E2+%2B+10%29%29). The solution comprises several voluminous terms so I will not attempt to write it out here. Using the simpler approximate solution also offered by Wolfram Alpha with double-precision computation results in values of $x$ that generally seem to be accurate to within 1% of the true result.